# Redis 7: are .aof files backward compatible?

Tags: redis

According to [redis persistance doc](https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/), redis 7 introduces a multi-part AOF mechanism.

> Since Redis 7.0.0, Redis uses a multi part AOF mechanism. That is, the original single AOF file is split into base file (at most one) and incremental files (there may be more than one).

The result is that while previous versions of redis produced a single `appendonly.aof` file, redis now produces multiple files.

Is it possible to launch an older redis-server based on these files? i.e run redis 6.2.5 based on the information found in these files?
Alternatively, is it possible to merge the incremental aof files into one `aof` file that can be used in older versions of redis?